# not able to play video available in local project of angular 2

Tags: angular

my html page:

```
<div class="center" >  
        <video width="400" controls (click)="toggleVideo()" #videoPlayer>
            <source src="{{"movie.mp4"}}" type="video/mp4" />
            Browser not supported
        </video>        
</div>
```

component

```
<div class="center" >  
    <video width="400" controls (click)="toggleVideo()" #videoPlayer>
        <source src="{{"movie.mp4"}}" type="video/mp4" />
        Browser not supported
    </video>
```

not able to play a video available in myproject.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any error in the browser console?

Comment: @ManikandanMurugesan if you are using static source of video then you should not use interpolation. provided it as `src="path_to_video"` and your video should be placed in assets folder, you can access it using 'src="/assets/movie.mp4"`

Comment: Why src is like this src="{{"movie.mp4"}}? If you are using {{}} so you have to use variable from ts  then src is like src="{{variable-name-here}}"

Comment: i have like this  <source src="/Home/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  i get the console error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)